# Remove NavigationBar background when clipped onto a RoundedCornerShape - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm new to Compose. How do I remove this background on NavigationBar? When I open up layout inspector it indicates that Scaffold is the culprit, I have set Scaffold's Insets to 0dp.

[image]

My Modifier on Navigation bar is as follows:

```
NavigationBar(
  modifier = Modifier
    // ... other modifiers
    .graphicsLayer {
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 25, topEndPercent = 25)
        clip = true
    }
) { // content }
```

Comment: Your code perfectly works for me. please check the library versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the Scaffold's paddingValues that messed it up...

```
Scaffold(
  // ...
) { padding -> // the culprit!!!!
   // ...
}
```